# md-option elements change appearance and behaviour on hover and select

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, angular-material

I am using `md-select` and `md-option` to generate a language chooser dropdown. Therefor we are not only displaying the language string but also using [flag-icon-css](http://flag-icon-css.lip.is/) in order to display the corresponding country flag.

In this scenario I am experiencing a strage behaviuor which I believe to come out of the box with the `md-select` element. Namely the `md-select` elements are rendered correctly except for the one which is already selected and the one you hover over with the mouse.

We are using a typescript class in the background which holds the needed information and the html looks like this:

```
  <md-select ng-model="login.selectedLanguage" class="lang-select {{login.selectedLanguage}}">
    <md-option ng-repeat="lang in login.languages" value="{{lang.langKey}}" ng-click="login.changeLang(lang.langKey)" class="lang-option">
      {{lang.text}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
```

We are also using css classes which are packed in a `sass` file where the corresponding flags are set. **Notice:** Here I omitted the css class for the `md-select` itself as it works as expected.

```
@mixin flag($country)
  background-image: url('#{$ROOT}/bower_components/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/#{$country}.svg')

.lang-select
  margin-top: 22px

.lang-option
  padding-left: 50px
  background: no-repeat 10px center
  background-size: 30px 20px
  text-transform: none

.lang-option[value="de_DE"]
  +flag('de')

.lang-option[value="en_EN"]
  +flag('gb')

.lang-option[value="fr_FR"]
  +flag('fr')
```

Like I said before every time I hover an element the flag disappears and it looks like it is moved out of the dropdown's scope as I am sure that I can notice a slight movement of the flag to the top left when I hover. And the result looks like this:

[image]

In the figure I am currently hovering over `english` and french (Francais) is the currently selected element.

I wasn't able to reproduce the entire setup in a fiddle as I didn't know how to intergate our sass code.

**Therefor the flags in my fiddle are hard coded tags and do not disappear on hover or select**. But what you can see in the fiddle is that the default behavior of the `md-select` changes the hovered item's background on default. I believe that this is the very same functionality which makes our flags disappear. [Please try the fiddle for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaese/ozohntj2/5/)

It is of course possible that I am mistaken and my css code is responsible for the behaviour. But I do not have any hovering code implemented. If I am mistaken please let me know.

So the question is how do I suppress this behaviour in order to always show the flags in `md-option`?

**UPDATE:**

After I set `background-position: center` it seems even more clearly that there is some kind of animation behind all this as I now can see how the flag slides in from out of the container's scope.

Regards

---

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does not work, because your are setting the `background-image` property via CSS and on hover/select Angular Material changes the background of the element.

What you could probably do is actually the same you did in your fiddle. Instead of setting the background image on the md-option element you could just add a span inside and apply it there:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="lang in login.languages" value="{{lang.langKey}}" ng-click="login.changeLang(lang.langKey)" class="lang-option">
  <span class="flag-container"></span> {{lang.text}}
</md-option>
```

Not familiar with the SASS syntax so I write this in plain CSS. You'll know what I mean :)

```
.lang-option[value="de_DE"] .flag-container {
    background-image: url('PATH-TO-DE-FLAG.svg')
}
```

Hope this solves your problem :)